# Change source (url) of Server-Sent event

Tags: javascript, php, server-sent-events

How can I change the source set in declaration of `EventSource`?

I have tried something like this:

```
var source = new EventSource("/blahblah.php?path=" + (window.location.pathname));
// Few lines later...
source.url = "/blahblah.php?path=" + url;
```

But, `source.url` stays the same...

Is this even possible? Or maybe there are alternative ways to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not possible. A new URL passed to `EventSource()`  creates  a new `EventSource` object.

Comment: Ok... Thanks for help. I am wondering, why changing the url is not possible.

Comment: Why do you want to change the URL?

Comment: because I'm creating autorefreshing single-page forums with possibility to share using url bar...

Comment: You could possibly utilize `ServiceWorker` to intercept all requests from a domain. Have not tried push notification, though that could be an option. Why would a different `EventSource` object be necessary for new URL? When new URL is created, why could  not same URL for `EventSource` be used for each new URL?

Comment: @Soaku _"I am wondering, why changing the url is not possible. "_ _"The resource indicated in the argument to the EventSource constructor is fetched when the constructor is run."_ [9.2 Server-sent events - 9.2.2 The EventSource interface - 9.2.3 Processing model](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/comms.html#sse-processing-model)

Comment: Have you got any idea how to pass vars from client to sse file? If yes, then it would solve the problem... it would be the simplest way.

Comment: @Soaku _"Have you got any idea how to pass vars from client to sse file?"_ When you pass URL to `EventSource()` search query parameters can be concatenated, at `php` you can get parameters with `$_GET["key"]`

Answer (score 0):

I Do it like this.

```
var source;

function ChangeEventSource(Url) {

    if (source != undefined) {source.close(); }
    
    if (typeof (EventSource) !== "undefined") {
    
        source = new EventSource(Url);
        source.onmessage = function (event) { 
                //Do something here
        };
        
    } else {
        console.log("Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...");
    }
}
```